# UDP multicast - send and receive in one process

Tags: c++, udp, boost-asio, ipv6, multicast

I have a third party service. This service will send an answer if you send a request via udp multicast (ipv6). I want to send the request on every ipv6 capable networkdevice.

I used boost and the sender and receiver example (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/multicast/) to send a request and revice the result. I only changed the ip address and the request string.

I tracked the data via wireshark and my request isn't using the specified port (the port is random). So my receiver doesn't get the data from the service.

I'm not very familar with udp and the boost::asio framework. Maybe there is a better way to achieve my goal.

My C++ code looks like:

```
asio::ip::address listenerAddress = asio::ip::address::from_string("my ipv6 address");
asio::ip::address multicastAddress = asio::ip::address::from_string("FF02::3");

asio::io_service io_service;

receiver r(io_service, listenerAddress, multicastAddress);
sender s(io_service, multicastAddress);

io_service.run();
```

Comment: Source port should be random. However, destination port must be the one you've defined. Are you sure that you are checking the right port?

Comment: I'm pretty sure. I got some C# code where everything works as expected. But I've to write the same logic in C++. When I start my C++ receiver and the C# sender I'm getting the expected result in C++. That's why I'm thinking my C++ receiver is doing his job very well. I added some code in my post.